# Flutter MapBox iOS crash on start

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, crash, mapbox

I am new to Flutter and trying to integrate a MapBox map with Turn by Turn navigation in an iOS and Android app.

I am using the [flutter_mapbox_navigation](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mapbox_navigation) package and [MapBoxNavigationView](https://github.com/eopeter/flutter_mapbox_navigation/blob/master/lib/src/embedded/view.dart).

I cannot run the iOS app anymore as it always crashes a few seconds after launch. It was working before but now it crashes and I do not understand why. I do not see any error message or log or anything.

I tried commenting the `Center` widget and all its children and it works fine.

I am on macOS Monterey 12.3.1 (Apple M1)

Console output:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone SE (3rd generation) in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                           11,4s
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:49961/xmxNQnLdNHE=/ws
Lost connection to device.
Exited
```

main.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_mapbox_navigation/library.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final _options = MapBoxOptions();
  Future<void> _onRouteEvent(e) async {}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Column(
        children: [
          const Text("test"),
          Center(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 300,
              height: 200,
              child: MapBoxNavigationView(
                options: _options,
                onRouteEvent: _onRouteEvent,
                onCreated: (MapBoxNavigationViewController controller) async {},
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

pubspec.yml

```yaml
name: poc
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.0 <3.0.0"

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_mapbox_navigation: ^0.0.26

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been dealing with this problem too for a while.
Try one of these:

#### 1. Updating the "`Info.plist`"

(Referencing: [issue:463](https://github.com/flutter-mapbox-gl/maps/issues/463))
I resolved the issue by opening "`ios/Runner/Info.plist`" and adding the
following lines in between the
`<dict>...</dict>`.

```
<key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
<true/>
<key>MGLMapboxMetricsEnabledSettingShownInApp</key>
<true/>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Shows your location on the map and helps improve the map</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Shows your location on the map and helps improve the map</string>
```

Also, execute the following commands in the root folder:

`flutter clean` (to clean up the project)

`flutter create .` (to add any missing files)

#### 2. Running on actual device and not iOS simulator

For me, the method above didn't work but it seemed to have worked for others so I thought it was worth mentioning. It seems that Mapbox has a hard time working on Apple Silicon iOS simulators(ref: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native-ios/issues/558)

But running it on your own device seems to work, at least for me.
Following this: https://codeburst.io/wireless-debugging-ios-run-debug-install-builds-over-wifi-a48fc49ac3a7 you can run it wirelessly on your iPhone. Hope this helps.

PS: If you get the "iproxy cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified", you can delete the `/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts` directory and run `flutter run` again.

Comment: thanks so much! Number 1 solved it for me.